# Missing right parenthesis while executing this query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
Select a.*, 
when to_number(prem_term='annually')then to_number(prem_amt×1)
when to_number(prem_term='quaterly') then 
to_number(prem_amt×4)
when to_number(prem_term='semi annually') then 
to_number(prem_amt×2)Else end
From policy_holder a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `CASE` and value you'd want to return in case of `ELSE`, superfluous  & invalid `TO_NUMBER` function calls. Maybe you wanted something like this:

```
SELECT a.*,
       CASE
          WHEN prem_term = 'annually'      THEN prem_amt * 1
          WHEN prem_term = 'quaterly'      THEN prem_amt * 4
          WHEN prem_term = 'semi annually' THEN prem_amt * 2
          ELSE NULL
       END
  FROM policy_holder a;
```

Comment: And `*`, not `x`.

Comment: Ha! I imagined it were different column names, not *multiplication* signs, @Alex. Thank you!

Comment: In sql developer software * is used as both star and multiply